# Configure MSLocalDB in a .NET config file

Tags: sql-server, configuration, c#

I have created a .NET Standard C# project and a SQL database in my LocalDB server (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
I have tried to configure the connection string in the project web configuration file but in runtime the connection to SQL server is not succeeded. 
How can I configure a local DB server in my project config file?

This is the connection string configured in my project web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="iPark.Database.Properties.Settings.iParkConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=iPark;User ID=iParkUser;Password=iParkPassword1"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I try to access the database, the following error occurs:

[image]

Relative to the database, I've created the user iParkUser with authentication type "SQL Server Authentication". I can login to the server and the database with the user and its roles are the following:

- db_owner
- db_reader
- db_writer

Comment: Would we be able to get the full connection string you are using?  What is the error message that you are getting?  It could be a permissions issue for the account running the application, an issue with the driver.  Are you able to connect to the same SQL instance from something else like `SSMS`?

Comment: Yes, I’m traveling and I haven’t my pc right here but tomorrow in the monrning, I share that informations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comment updated.

Comment: Are you currently working on this web application from your local machine?  (I am assuming this is yes, but for my sake I want to ask) Is the exact same value (special characters and all) used in your `SSMS` instance the same value you are using for your SQL Connection in the config file?

Comment: Yes, it is! Ahahah I’m working on my local machine with a local website. I have a hostname assigned to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file.

Comment: Does the Windows Application log provide more details?

Comment: Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 05/07/2019 22:23:33  
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/8/ROOT/iPark.UI-1-132068346827044054 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /iPark.UI 
    Application Path: C:\MyProjects\iPark\iPark.UI\ 
    Machine name: ITSDAAS-10221 
 
Process information: 
- Process ID: 25912 
- Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ipedro.ipark.local

Comment: Thanks in advance to all the help.